# Textbox Height 100% When Parent Div has Margins

Tags: asp.net, css, html

Browsed some related questions but none seemed to answer mine.

I have something like the following:

```
<div id="outerdiv" style="width: 50%; height: 100%">
    <div id="innerdiv" style="margin: 5px; height: 100%">
         <textbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the textbox to take up the full space of the inner div that has margins. Two problems:

If the inner div has height 100%, it overflows because it has margins. I can't have padding on the outer div because the outer div then overflows it's parent etc. The whole layout is a square with four equal sub-squares where each subsquare is like the markup above.

1. So how can I get the innerdiv to take up the full height but still have the margin I want?

If I set the textbox to 100% width and height, again the margin causes problems and the textbox overflows.

1. How can I make the textbox take up the full space without overflowing?

**Edit**:

Fiddles:
use this as base and add an outer div with a fixed width and height to see my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/7w8TA/

This is a fiddle I created myself but I'm not sure if it's public or not... : http://jsfiddle.net/LethalLava/mY6Dn/

Comment: can you setup a fiddle ?

Comment: Edited with some fiddle links.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you:
http://jsfiddle.net/7w8TA/

```
<div style="width:400px; height:300px">
<div id="outerdiv" style="width: 50%; height: 100%;border:1px solid black" >
    <div id="innerdiv" style="margin: 5px; height: 100%;border:1px solid red" >
        <input type="text" value="textbox" style="width:98%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mY6Dn/4/

Comment: Yes, that's close but it's not my exact scenario. Never used fiddle before so hope this works, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/LethalLava/mY6Dn/ . Hopefully it is public... I just added a div outside your outer div and set a fixed size on it: 400px width and 300px height. The problem then appears. Also, the textbox doesn't fill up the full height.

Comment: okey I see. If the outside div width is not dynamic you can adjust the textbox width using width:99% or a similar value.
http://jsfiddle.net/mY6Dn/4/

Comment: If there's no "exact" way of achieving this that's really sad... Thanks anyways.